# Does Clojure use multiple threads in a map call?

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting to explore the behavior of a CPU-bound algorithm as it scales to multiple CPUs using Clojure. The algorithm takes a large sequence of consecutive integers as input, partitions the sequence into a given number of sub-sequences, then uses map to apply a function to each sub-sequence. Once the map function has completed, reduce is used to collect the results.

The full code is available on [Github](https://github.com/joshpeterson/nash-clojure/blob/master/src/nash_clojure/core.clj), but here is a sample:

```
(map computation-function (partitioning-function number-of-partitions input))
```

When I execute this code on a machine with twelve cores, I see most of the the cores in use, when I expect to see only one core in use.

Ideally, I would like to use `pmap` to use a given number of threads, but I am unable to cause the code to execute using only one thread.

So is Clojure spreading the computation across multiple CPUs? If so, is there anything that I can do to control this behavior?

Comment: First, add `(println "Thread: " (.getName (Thread/currentThread)))` to   prove it's actually executing in multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging suggestion, I believe that I have found the cause of the problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that `pmap` uses multiple cores and `map` uses the current thread only. (There would be no point in having both functions in the library if both used all available cores.)

The following simple experiment shows that `pmap` uses separate threads and `map` does not:

```
(defn something-slow [x]
  (Thread/sleep 1000))

(map something-slow (range 5))
;; Takes 5 seconds
(pmap something-slow (range 5))
;; Takes 1 second
```

I do note that your GitHub code uses `pmap` in the example which runs in `main-`; if you change back to `map` does the parallelism persist?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more clear above. I have attempted to use both map and pmap (although the code on Github is using pmap by default). In this case, I tested with the pmap code deleted to ensure that I was using map!

Comment: Well, a second look at my code confirms your suspicion. I must have been using pmap without realizing it, because the code is now behaving as you described. Thanks!